# Sequential string chunking

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, text-mining, nested-lists

I have a list of strings that I am looking to chunk into sub-lists comprising three  elements, the element in the list (i), the preceding element (i-1), and the next element (i+1). I would also be looking to iterate over *every other* element in the list rather than every element. More specifically, how can I go from this...

```
mylist = ['red','green','blue','yellow','orange','purple','black']
```

To this... (starting from index position 1 to enable a preceding element);

```
mysublists = [['green','red','blue'],['yellow','blue','orange'],['purple','orange','black']]
```

So each item in the sub-list contains every second element as its' first item, followed by the item that *preceded* it in the original list, followed by the item that *succeeded* it in the original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip` and list slicing:

```
res = [[j, i, k] for i, j, k in zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2], mylist[2::2])]

[['green', 'red', 'blue'],
 ['yellow', 'blue', 'orange'],
 ['purple', 'orange', 'black']]
```

Or use `list` with `zip` directly for a list of tuples:

```
res = list(zip(mylist[1::2], mylist[::2], mylist[2::2]))
```

If you want a list of lists with similar syntax, you can use `map`:

```
res = list(map(list, zip(mylist[1::2], mylist[::2], mylist[2::2])))
```

Comment: Or `[list(t) for t in zip(mylist[1::2], mylist[::2], mylist[2::2]))]` I guess

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution without list comprehension and zip, you could do the following:

```
def chunk_list(list_to_chunk):
    buffer_list = []
    for index in range(1, len(list_to_chunk) - 1):
        new_list = [list_to_chunk[index], \
                    list_to_chunk[index-1], list_to_chunk[index+1]]

        buffer_list.append(new_list)

    return buffer_list
```

The code uses a for-loop over every index from 1 to the second last index (`range`).